# (css) how to display a div up as compared to the other divs

Tags: css

I am trying to create a page like this:

[image: Example image]

All the things are going fine where as i am not able to create the first div which is looking little a bit up as compared to the other divs. it also has a border-bottom shadow. Please guide me how can i create the similar image using css.
Thanks..

Comment: Could you show us your code? Otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Up = along z-axis? It is only `box-shadow` property which is creating an effect that it is above others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing special about the first item is the shadow which creates that depth effect, you can try something like this to reproduce it:

```
li:first-child{
    background: #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/2N4Yr/)**